# How can I copy a struct member array to a variable?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have the following basic C example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Example {
    double arr[4][4];
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    struct Example e = {
        {{1., 0., 0., 0.},
         {0., 1., 0., 0.},
         {0., 0., 1., 0.},
         {0., 0., 0., 1.}},
         4
    };
    double** arr = e.arr;

    printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2], arr[0][3]);
    printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[1][0], arr[1][1], arr[1][2], arr[1][3]);
    printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[2][0], arr[2][1], arr[2][2], arr[2][3]);
    printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[3][0], arr[3][1], arr[3][2], arr[3][3]);
}
```

What do I have to do to make the `printf` successfully print out the values in the matrix? If I declare `arr` as `double**` I get a segfault. If I try `double*` then it complains when I try to do double indexing. I've also tried `double arr[4][4] = e.arr`, but the compiler just tells me that it's an invalid initializer.  What's the proper way to do this?

(I realize `size` is redundant in this example, I just wanted the struct to have more than one member.)

Comment: You can use a pointer to array like this `double (*arr)[4] = e.arr`. Note that `e.arr` is the same as `&e.arr[0]`, but `&e.arr[0]` is the address of an entire array with 4 `double`s (a line of the 2D matrix), so you need a pointer that can point to an entire array of length 4.

Comment: There is no copy of the array being made here, you are actually storing the address of the array in a pointer variable, so the pointer points to the original array, and the values printed belong to the original array, not a copy of it.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ will be helpful background information for you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this since the values of double arr[4][4] are consecutive in memory

```
double* arr = e.arr[0]; // points to first value

printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[8], arr[9], arr[10], arr[11]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr[12], arr[13], arr[14], arr[15]);
```

or alternatively, as @ismick pointed out in his comment you can write it like

```
double (*arr2)[4] = e.arr ;

printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr2[0][0], arr2[0][1], arr2[0][2], arr2[0][3]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr2[1][0], arr2[1][1], arr2[1][2], arr2[1][3]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr2[2][0], arr2[2][1], arr2[2][2], arr2[2][3]);
printf("%8.5f %8.5f %8.5f %8.5f\n", arr2[3][0], arr2[3][1], arr2[3][2], arr2[3][3]);
```

if you want that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the answer given by @AndersK, you can also try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Example {
    double arr[4][4];
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    struct Example e = {
        {{1., 0., 0., 0.},
         {0., 1., 0., 0.},
         {0., 0., 1., 0.},
         {0., 0., 0., 1.}},
         4
    };
    double *arr = (double *)e.arr;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            printf("%8.5f ", *(arr+i*4+j));
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this we are pointing to the first block of memory where `e.arr[0]` is stored, then we are traversing through the consecutive memory location using this expression `(arr+i*4+j)`.